# use dictionary of words for email spam classification

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, classification

trying to use the dictionary function containing most common words within the csv file. not sure how to go about using the function within the trainTest function as im new to python programming and have had a few errors trying.

```
def dictionary():
f = open("spam_ham_dataset.csv",'r')
stopRemoved = set(stopwords.words("english"))
allWords = ' '.join(f)
allWords = allWords.split()
dictionary = Counter(allWords)
for item in allWords:
    if len(item) == 1:
        del dictionary[item]
    if item.isdigit():
        del dictionary[item]
    if item == "subject":
        del dictionary[item]
    if item == string.punctuation:
        del dictionary[item]
    if item in stopRemoved:
        del dictionary[item]
    if item == '""':
        del dictionary[item]
    if item == '.",0':
        del dictionary[item]
    if item == '",1':
        del dictionary[item]
dic = dict(dictionary.most_common(100))
#print(dic)
#word_cloud = WordCloud(width=1600, height=1600, background_color='white',
#min_font_size=12).generate_from_frequencies(dic)
# plt.imshow(word_cloud)
#plt.axis("off")
#plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
#plt.show()
#word_cloud.to_file('test1.png')
return dic

def trainTest(emails):
allEnronEmails = emails
allEnronEmails['text'].head().apply(cleanAll)
matrix = CountVectorizer(analyzer=cleanAll).fit_transform(allEnronEmails['text'])
print(matrix.shape)
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(matrix, allEnronEmails['label_num'],
                                                test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
#naiveBayes = MultinomialNB()
#naiveBayes.fit(trainX, trainY)
#predictionNBTrain = naiveBayes.predict(trainX)
#print(classification_report(trainY, predictionNBTrain))
#print('Confusion Matrix: \n', confusion_matrix(trainY, predictionNBTrain))
#print()
#print('Accuracy: ', accuracy_score(trainY, predictionNBTrain))

#predictionNBTest = naiveBayes.predict(testX)
#p = trainY.values
#print(classification_report(testY, predictionNBTest))
#print('Confusion Matrix: \n', confusion_matrix(testY, predictionNBTest))
#print()
#print('Accuracy: ', accuracy_score(testY, predictionNBTest))
```

if I call the function with the use of the dictionary of words this is the error I get below. As the words are not in the csv file format anymore im not sure how to get around this as I have been using the different fields for classification.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hollyevans/PycharmProjects/Project/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    trainTestEnron = trainTest(enronDictionary)
  File "/Users/hollyevans/PycharmProjects/Project/Enron.py", line 74, in trainTest
    allEnronEmails['text'].head().apply(cleanAll)
KeyError: 'text'
```

Comment: Not related: If you look at your stack of `if`s, the action you do satisfying any of which is same. In that case, you can use one `if` with a logical concat.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m not 100% on what you are meaning with the phrasing. Could you give an example